# Can SFTP connector and EDIFACT connector be implemented in Mule Community Edition?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I created a mule application in Mule Enterprise Edition 3.7.3 in Anypoint Studio which has a SFTP connector endpoint and an EDIFACT Connector. It was working fine in the embedded server of Anypoint Studio. When I tried to deploy the application in Mule 3.7.0 standalone Runtime CE, it showed a license error.
I want to know, can I use in CE or I need to create my own connectors for both of them. The error is given below :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/mulesource/licm/LicenseKeyException
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
>           at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
>   ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the EDIFACT connector that's only available on EE runtimes and i think that maybe an additional B2B license is needed, SFTP is available for CE.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/

By default Anypoint Studio uses an Mule Enterprise runtime when running and debugging in Studio. I would recommend to install the CE runtime in Studio so you actually know that what you are developing is able to run on the CE runtime in your instance.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/adding-community-runtime

Comment: Thanks for the information @JoostD. So, I need to write my custom EDIFACT connector for using in Community Runtime? Is there any other way out for using the connectors in CE?

Comment: You need to create custom logic to do the transformation, doesn't need to be a connector, depends on your needs. If you read the file from SFTP do the transformation with a custom transformer, JAVA, Groovy, etc

Answer (score 0):

The Community Edition is not licensed to use connectors/features that were specifically built for the Enterprise runtime. The Community Edition can use all of the Community connectors/features. Enterprise runtime can run both community and enterprise connectors.

Anypoint Studio provides the ability to use and execute enterprise features/connectors WITHIN the embedded Enterprise runtime of Studio. Once you need to use those enterprise features/connectors outside of Studio you need a licensed Enterprise runtime.